# Failed WordPress Update - This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to update WordPress to the version 5.2.1, but always I am getting the following error:

```
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-5.2.1-no-content.zip…

Unpacking the update…

The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php

Installation Failed
```

I saw many other solutions like below, but I am afraid to use them as I am not sure how this will affect the security and the functionality of the plugins.

Reset the permissions of all files to 664:

```
find /path/to/site/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Reset permissions of directories to 775:

```
find /path/to/site/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Reset the group to the wordpress group (or whatever group makes sense for you)

```
chgrp -R wordpress /path/to/site/
```

Does any other way for detecting which exact file or folder has the problem so as to avoid making mass changes on the files' and folders' permissions?

Answer (score 4):

Before proceeding I recommend to make a **full** backup of your files and database just in case, then you should be able to run those commands, they should not affect the security of WordPress as they are documented on **[Hardening WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#changing-file-permissions)**

Be aware that sometimes file permissions are affected also depending on the **[group](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions)**, so in that case find the group WordPress should belong and run:

```sh
# replace "www-data" with the group that WordPress has access to.

chown -R www-data:www-data 

# Example:

chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/site/
```

What I do to find sometimes what group is allowed to write onto WordPress is basically just to upload an **Image** at the media library, if WordPress allows the upload without issues then whatever group the `wp-content/uploads/` folder has, **should be the correct one**, or you can also refresh the [permalinks](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/) and look up the same group information on the `.htaccess` to get the correct group information.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you use selinux than it can be a problem with your `secontext`.

Check your logs:

```sh
sudo ausearch -m avc --start recent
```

Your selinux blocks updates if you have something like this:

```
time->Fri Jun 19 14:55:53 2020
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1363292157.560:188): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=29495 comm="httpd"  exe="/usr/sbin/httpd"
name="update-core.php" dev="md126" ino=30 scontext=scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=file
```

You can check [this](https://noobient.com/2019/02/28/updating-wordpress-on-centos-with-enabled-selinux/) in order to set a more permissive secontext

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is relatively old - but I think this might be one for anyone in the unfortunate position of having to use Wordpress on IIS. I got the same error the last couple of days on a previously working site. Lots of looking around - hence I found this page - around the ideas of Permissions on directories. In my case - indeed - in the case of IIS - I had experimentally turned on the Basic Authentication module (way easier using .htaccess etc) and even there was only a subdirectory turned into a Application for the purposes of testing - that it was just one level down from the root of the install - turning it on caused permissions issues with updates - but bizarrely not with fresh plugin installs. Been running web servers over 25 years - never seen this one before - hope not to see it again.

Simple solution - stick to LAMP,  XAMP, or MAMP